# Include wildcard (%) in Django 'contains' query

Tags: django, django-queryset

According to Django docs

```
Entry.objects.get(headline__contains='Lennon')
```

Roughly translates to this SQL:

```
SELECT ... WHERE headline LIKE '%Lennon%';
```

But if I want to do somethng like this (removing a wildcard):

```
SELECT ... WHERE headline LIKE '%Lennon';
```

What would the Django query be?

Answer (score 1):

The keywords for partial field lookups you are looking for are [`startswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#startswith) and [`endswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#endswith):

```
Entry.objects.filter(headline__startswith='Lennon')
Entry.objects.filter(headline__endswith='Lennon')
```

You can also use the case insensitive variants, `istartswith` and `iendswith`:

```
Entry.objects.filter(headline__istartswith='lennon')
Entry.objects.filter(headline__iendswith='lennon')
```

Comment: Django covers trivial cases. It would be great to cover something like `...LIKE 'foo_bar%baz%'` '_' match any 1 character and  ' %' used in the middle of the word

Comment: @hipertracker You can use a regex search for more complex cases: `Entry.objects.filter(headline__regex='^foo_bar.*baz.*$')`. According to [the Django devs](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17473) the performance penalty is negligible for PostgreSQL.